# Best practice for ITargetBlock<TInput>.Completion.ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, tpl-dataflow

This question is about best practices when using `ContinueWith()` to handle a TPL datablock's completion.

The [`ITargetBlock<TInput>.Completion()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194810%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method allows you to asynchronously handle a datablock's completion using [`ContinueWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Consider the following Console app code which demonstrates a very basic use:

```
private static void Main()
{
    test().Wait();
}

static async Task test()
{
    var transform = new TransformBlock<int, double>(i => i/2.0);
    var output    = new ActionBlock<double>(d => Console.WriteLine(d));

    // Warning CS4014 here:
    transform.Completion.ContinueWith(continuation => output.Complete());
    transform.LinkTo(output);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        await transform.SendAsync(i);

    transform.Complete();
    await output.Completion;
}
```

The code has a very simple [`TransformBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which divides integers by 2.0 and turns them into doubles. The transformed data is processed by an [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which just outputs the values to the console window.

The output is:

```
0
0.5
1
1.5
2
2.5
3
3.5
4
4.5
```

When the `TransformBlock` is completed, I want to also complete the `ActionBlock`. It is convenient to do this like so:

```
transform.Completion.ContinueWith(continuation => output.Complete());
```

And here lies the issue. Because this is inside an `async` method and I'm ignoring the return value from `ContinueWith()`, I get a compiler warning:

> **warning CS4014: Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.**

Clearly I can't `await` the call as advised by the warning - if I do so, the code hangs up because the `CompleteWith()` task can't complete until `transform.Complete()` is called.

Now I don't have a problem with dealing with the warning itself (I can just suppress it or assign the task to a variable, or use a `.Forget()` task extension and so on) - but here's my questions:

- Is it safe to handle linked DataBlock completion in this way?
- Is there a better way?
- Is there anything important here that I've overlooked?

I think that if I was doing anything other than `output.Complete()` inside the continuation, I'd have to provide exception handling - but perhaps even just calling `output.Complete()` is fraught with peril?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can implement completion propagation yourself, TPL Dataflow does it for you with `DataflowLinkOptions.PropagateCompletion`:

```
transform.LinkTo(output, new DataflowLinkOptions {PropagateCompletion = true});
```

---

If you would still like to implement that yourself, you can solve the issue be storing the task and awaiting it when appropriate using `Task.WhenAll`:

```
static async Task test()
{
    var transform = new TransformBlock<int, double>(i => i/2.0);
    var output    = new ActionBlock<double>(d => Console.WriteLine(d));

    // Warning CS4014 here:
    var continuation = transform.Completion.ContinueWith(_ => output.Complete());
    transform.LinkTo(output);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        await transform.SendAsync(i);

    transform.Complete();
    await Task.WhenAll(continuation, output.Completion)
}
```

This enables you to handle any exceptions in `output.Complete` and to remove the warning.

Comment: which is not very clear from the documentation but seems to work. Link your mesh correctly and away you go.

Comment: Awesome! This is the answer, thanks. (My investigations into how exceptions are handled by data blocks have thrown up some further questions that I might ask at some point in the future... ;)